# How to find class ="class1" included class="class2" in CSS?

Tags: css

How to use css_selector find `<div class="class2"></div>`?

```
<div class="class1">
    <div>
        <div class="class2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think use css_selector_class find `<div class="class2"></div>`,How write the css_selector by class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the descendent selector () or be more specific with the child selector `>` like so

```
div.class1 > div > div.class2 { . . .} //any div.class2 in a div in a div.class1

div.class1 div.class2 { . . . } //any div.class2 that is a descendent of a div.class1
```

Per your comment on Tushar's answer, if you want to find a div with both `class1` and `class2`, the selector is like this

```
div.class1.class2 { . . . } //any div with both class1 and class2
```

Comment: sorry,I just use css_selector by class ,However, this code is not flexible
.I think  find all class2,if i have many class2

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Please update your question with more information.

Comment: Sorry, .class1 .class2{...},it is right,thanks

Comment: Ah, alright. Glad that took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this,

```
 .class1 > div > .class2 {
        //attributes goes here   
    }
```

here is the running plunk, http://plnkr.co/edit/auKaLriP3Dyxypw6Mm4V?p=preview

Comment: sorry for the typo....